# ManytoMany Mapping shows incorrect Result

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have created two Entities namely Employee and Projects, the code for Employee and Projects are shown below

Employee.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long empId;
@Column(name = "empName")
private String employeeName;
@Column(name = "designation")
private String designation;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "emp_project_detail",joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "e_id")},inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "p_id")})
private List<Project> projectList;
//getters and setters
```

Project.java

```
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "projectid")
private  Long projectId;
@Column(name = "projectname")
private  String projectName;
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "emp_project_detail",joinColumns ={@JoinColumn(name = "p_id")},inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "e_id")})
List<Employee> employeeList;
```

I have created an InsertController to assign multiple projects for the Employee as shown below

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/assignedProject")
private String project_empDetails(Model model){
    List<Employee> employeeList= new ArrayList<Employee>();
    List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<Project>();
   Session session =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   session.beginTransaction();
    Project project_1 =new Project("Banking Projects");
    Project project_2 =new Project("IT Projects");
    Employee employee_1 = new Employee("Arul","developer");
    Employee employee_2 = new Employee("Ankita","developer");
 employee_1.setProjectList(projects);
 employee_1.getProjectList().add(project_1);
 employee_1.getProjectList().add(project_2);
 session.save(employee_1);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    model.addAttribute("msg","Assigned Project Sucessfully");

    return "projectList";
```

After executing this,the values are stored in the tables "3 times", the console also shows that the values are stored in 3 times

```
 Hibernate: insert into employee (designation, emp_detailId, empName) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into project (projectname) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into project (projectname) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into emp_project_detail (e_id, p_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into emp_project_detail (e_id, p_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into employee (designation, emp_detailId, empName) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into project (projectname) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into project (projectname) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into emp_project_detail (e_id, p_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into emp_project_detail (e_id, p_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into employee (designation, emp_detailId, empName) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into project (projectname) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into project (projectname) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into emp_project_detail (e_id, p_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into emp_project_detail (e_id, p_id) values (?, ?)
```

The snapshot of the Tables are shown below

[image]
[image]

[image]

What wrong in the code?

Comment: I stopped reading after the two first code snippets. The mapping is incorrect. here's the documentation on how to create a bidirectional many to many association: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: Have a clear cut understanding on mapping, don't cascade in two entities, look at this https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many